# SonarCloud - `ECJ Unable to resolve type xxx` when scanning with Gradle 6.5.1 and Java 13.0.2

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube, sonarcloud

I am using Gradle scanner for analysis of my multi-project setup. When I run the analysis it works as expected but it gives me error logs like

> ECJ Unable to resolve type
> org.apache.commons.io.output.ByteArrayOutputStream
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.AbortCompilation: Pb(324)
> The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly
> referenced from required .class files.

The type that it asks me to resolve is not even used in my code so I am not able to figure out what is exactly happening.
I would be glad if anyone could tell me what does this error mean and how can it be resolved? Thanks.

**Project structure:-**

Project-CPRMS
| — build.gradle(root)
| — settings.gradle
| — carpark
| | — src
| | | — sub-project1
| | | | — build.gradle
| | | | — src
| | | | | — main
| | | | | — test
| | | — sub-project2
| | | | — build.gradle
| | | | — src
| | | | | — main
| | | | | — test

**Settings.gradle:-**

```
include "carpark:src:sub-project1"
include "carpark:src:sub-project2"
```

**build.gradle(root):-**

```
plugins {
  id "org.sonarqube" version "3.4.0.2513"
}

sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.host.url", "https://sonarcloud.io"
        property "sonar.projectKey", "myorg_cprms"
        property "sonar.organization", "myorg-github"
        property "sonar.language", "java"
        property "sonar.java.coveragePlugin", "jacoco"
        property "sonar.dynamicAnalysis", "reuseReports"
        property "sonar.jacoco.reportPath", "coverage/jacoco.exec"
        property "sonar.projectVersion", "1.2"
        property "sonar.java.source", "13"

        property "sonar.c.file.suffixes", "-"
        property "sonar.cpp.file.suffixes", "-"
        property "sonar.objc.file.suffixes", "-"
    }
}

subprojects {
  sonarqube {
      properties {
          property "sonar.sources", "src/main"
          property "sonar.tests", "src/test"
          property "sonar.java.libraries", "$projectDir/../sub-project1/build/libs/*.jar"
          property "sonar.java.binaries", "$projectDir/../sub-project1/build/classes/java,$projectDir/../sub-project2/build/classes/java"
          property "sonar.junit.reportsPath", "results"
          property "sonar.jacoco.reportPath", "coverage/carparkpro_jacoco_final.exec"
          property "sonar.exclusions", "**/test/**/*.java,**/*.js,**/*.xml,**/*.json,**/*.js.flow,**/*.sql,**/*.jsp,**/*.html,**/*.py,**/*.yml,**/*.css,**/*.ts"
      }
   }
}
```

**Command used to scan SonarCloud project:-**

> gradle sonarqube -x test -Dsonar.login=****

**ECJ Unable to resolve type related sample error stack trace(There are 100s of such errors):-**

> ECJ Unable to resolve type
> org.apache.commons.io.output.ByteArrayOutputStream
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.AbortCompilation: Pb(324)
> The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly
> referenced from required .class files at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.ProblemHandler.handle(ProblemHandler.java:162)
> at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.ProblemHandler.handle(ProblemHandler.java:229)
> at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.ProblemReporter.handle(ProblemReporter.java:2684)
> at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.ProblemReporter.isClassPathCorrect(ProblemReporter.java:5155)
> at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeFromCompoundName(LookupEnvironment.java:1791)
> at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeFromConstantPoolName(LookupEnvironment.java:1821)
> at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeFromConstantPoolName(LookupEnvironment.java:1829)
> at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeFromSignature(LookupEnvironment.java:1899)
> at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.createMethod(BinaryTypeBinding.java:1013)
> at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.createMethods(BinaryTypeBinding.java:1197)
> at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.cachePartsFrom(BinaryTypeBinding.java:611)
> at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.createBinaryTypeFrom(LookupEnvironment.java:1055)
> at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.createBinaryTypeFrom(LookupEnvironment.java:1036)
> at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.accept(Compiler.java:308)
> at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:257)
> at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getType(LookupEnvironment.java:1732)
> at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getType(LookupEnvironment.java:1701)
> at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTUtils.resolveType(ASTUtils.java:60) at
> org.sonar.java.model.JSema.resolveType(JSema.java:137) at
> org.sonar.java.model.JSema.lambda$getClassType$8(JSema.java:120) at
> java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1138) at
> org.sonar.java.model.JSema.getClassType(JSema.java:119) at
> org.sonar.java.model.JType.isSubtypeOf(JType.java:57) at
> org.sonar.java.se.checks.UnclosedResourcesCheck.needsClosing(UnclosedResourcesCheck.java:282)
> at
> org.sonar.java.se.checks.UnclosedResourcesCheck$PostStatementVisitor.methodOpeningResource(UnclosedResourcesCheck.java:523)
> at
> org.sonar.java.se.checks.UnclosedResourcesCheck$PostStatementVisitor.visitMethodInvocation(UnclosedResourcesCheck.java:509)
> at
> org.sonar.java.model.expression.MethodInvocationTreeImpl.accept(MethodInvocationTreeImpl.java:100)
> at
> org.sonar.java.se.checks.UnclosedResourcesCheck.checkPostStatement(UnclosedResourcesCheck.java:232)
> at
> org.sonar.java.se.CheckerDispatcher.executePost(CheckerDispatcher.java:112)
> at
> org.sonar.java.se.CheckerDispatcher.addTransition(CheckerDispatcher.java:103)
> at
> org.sonar.java.se.CheckerDispatcher.executePost(CheckerDispatcher.java:124)
> at
> org.sonar.java.se.CheckerDispatcher.addTransition(CheckerDispatcher.java:103)
> at
> org.sonar.java.se.checks.NullDereferenceCheck.checkPostStatement(NullDereferenceCheck.java:234)
> at
> org.sonar.java.se.CheckerDispatcher.executePost(CheckerDispatcher.java:112)
> at
> org.sonar.java.se.CheckerDispatcher.addTransition(CheckerDispatcher.java:103)
> at
> org.sonar.java.se.CheckerDispatcher.executeCheckPostStatement(CheckerDispatcher.java:75)
> at
> org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.executeMethodInvocation(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:825)
> at
> org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.visit(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:644)
> at
> org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.execute(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:262)
> at
> org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.visitMethod(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:218)
> at
> org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.visitMethod(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:210)
> at
> org.sonar.java.se.SymbolicExecutionVisitor.execute(SymbolicExecutionVisitor.java:79)
> at
> org.sonar.java.se.SymbolicExecutionVisitor.visitNode(SymbolicExecutionVisitor.java:65)
> at
> org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:100)
> at
> org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:125)
> at
> org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:102)
> at
> org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:125)
> at
> org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:102)
> at
> org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.scanTree(SubscriptionVisitor.java:83)
> at
> org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.scanFile(SubscriptionVisitor.java:69)
> at
> org.sonar.java.se.SymbolicExecutionVisitor.scanFile(SymbolicExecutionVisitor.java:55)
> at
> org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.lambda$runScanner$1(VisitorsBridge.java:260)
> at
> org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.runScanner(VisitorsBridge.java:265)
> at
> org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.runScanner(VisitorsBridge.java:260)
> at
> org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.visitFile(VisitorsBridge.java:243)
> at
> org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:132)
> at
> org.sonar.java.JavaFrontend.scanAsBatchCallback(JavaFrontend.java:247)
> at
> org.sonar.java.JavaFrontend.lambda$scanBatch$0(JavaFrontend.java:238)
> at
> org.sonar.java.model.JParserConfig$Batch$1.acceptAST(JParserConfig.java:181)
> at
> org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnitResolver.resolve(CompilationUnitResolver.java:1143)
> at
> org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnitResolver.resolve(CompilationUnitResolver.java:739)
> at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser.createASTs(ASTParser.java:1049)
> at
> org.sonar.java.model.JParserConfig$Batch.parse(JParserConfig.java:165)
> at org.sonar.java.JavaFrontend.scanBatch(JavaFrontend.java:238) at
> org.sonar.java.JavaFrontend.scanInBatches(JavaFrontend.java:228) at
> org.sonar.java.JavaFrontend.scanAsBatch(JavaFrontend.java:195) at
> org.sonar.java.JavaFrontend.scan(JavaFrontend.java:170) at
> org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSensor.execute(JavaSensor.java:113) at
> org.sonar.scanner.sensor.AbstractSensorWrapper.analyse(AbstractSensorWrapper.java:62)
> at
> org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:75)
> at
> org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.lambda$execute$1(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:48)
> at
> org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.withModuleStrategy(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:66)
> at
> org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:48)
> at
> org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:64)
> at
> org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:123)
> at
> org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:109)
> at
> org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:458)
> at
> org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:454)
> at
> org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:451)
> at
> org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:451)
> at
> org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:451)
> at
> org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:410)
> at
> org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:123)
> at
> org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:109)
> at
> org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.doAfterStart(GlobalContainer.java:130)
> at
> org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:123)
> at
> org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:109)
> at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute(Batch.java:58) at
> org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:52) at
> org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) at
> org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy78.execute(Unknown Source) at
> org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
> at
> org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
> at org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask.run(SonarQubeTask.java:102) at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) at
> org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104) at
> org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:49)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:42)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:726)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:693)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:569)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:395)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:387)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:157)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:242)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:150)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:84)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:554)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:537)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$300(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:108)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:278)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:267)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$1(ExecuteStep.java:33)
> at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:362) at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:33)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:67)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:36)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:49)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:34)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:43)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:34)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:44)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:54)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:38)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:159)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:72)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:43)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:44)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:33)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:92)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:85)
> at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:258) at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:39)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:76)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:94)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:49)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:79)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:53)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:74)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
> at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:362) at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:34)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:39)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:40)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:28)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:194)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:186)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:114)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:409)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:399)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:157)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:242)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:150)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:94)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
> at
> org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
> at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:356)
> at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
> at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
> at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
> at
> org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
> at
> org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
> at
> org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
> at
> org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)

Comment: Any update on this